# Magento 2: get all values of an EAV

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, product-attribute, eav

I have defined a custom attribute for my products, and now would like to get a list of all values I have entered for this attribute, not for a specific product, but in general.

It is a text field, it doesn't have any predefined options. Thus, `getAllOptions()` on the attribute object does not work.

How do I get a list of all entered values for the attribute?

**Edit:**

I got it to work now. You have to use the `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection`, then you can alter the collection like this:

```
    $productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('attributeName')->groupByAttribute('attributeName')->load();
    return $productCollection->getColumnValues('attributeName');
```

This returns an array of all values saved for this attribute.

Comment: You need to load the collection and get all column values.

Comment: Thanks, that and the usage of the ProductCollection instead of accessing the attributes themselves did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work now. You have to use the `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection`, then you can alter the collection like this:

```
    $productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('attributeName')->groupByAttribute('attributeName')->load();
    return $productCollection->getColumnValues('attributeName');
```

This returns an array of all values saved for this attribute.